# ISO 9797 MAC algorithm 3 for 7 bytes

Tags: mac, des, standards

I should implement [ISO 9797 MAC algorithm 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9797-1#MAC_algorithm_3) with initial transformation 1, without truncation, and using DES as a block cipher.

I should add padding of `0x80`, then enough zero bytes if the length is not multiple of 8.

- I want to know what will happen if data is only 8 bytes?
- I should feed data directly to 3DES algorithm or I should first feed it to des then feed to 3DES?

Comment: This is commonly called retail MAC, it requires DES CBC followed by decrypt with key 2, encrypt with key 1 or 3 depending on 2 or 3 key triple DES (2TDEA is assumed it seems). That means that the last vector & data perform a full triple DES block encrypt.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: BTW I always wondered if this is called _retail_ MAC because it was designed for / used in retail applications, or because DES is done again in the tail!

Comment: @fgrieu As far as I understood it was the first option / banking, but that's hearsay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know what will happen if data is only 8 bytes?

If the data is already 8 bytes then you need an additional block that contains `8000000000000000` (15 `0`s) since the [Padding method 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9797-1#Padding) is mandates adding `1` and necessary `0`'s.

Note that the Padding Mechanism 2 is not byte-oriented, it is bit-oriented. Whenever the data finishes you add `1` and add necessary zeros in minimal so that the data size is multiple of the chosen block cipher.

> for 7 bytes

In this case, you just add `0x80`. 7 zeroes are added after 1 to fit 64.

> I should feed data directly to 3DES algorithm or I should first feed it to DES then feed it to 3DES?

This MAC is as known as

- ANSI Retail-MAC
- CBC-MAC-Y or
- ISO/IEC 9797-1 algorithm 3.

With the DES it is also called the DES Retail MAC and uses two keys $K$ and $K'$.

Firstly it works as DES-CBC then the output performed like 3DES in Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt with two keys on the last block x-ored with $H_{q-1}$. One doesn't need a 3DES implementation to achieve this.

\begin{align}
H_1 & = e_K(D_1) \\
H_i & = e_K(D_i \oplus H_{i-1}), \quad (2 \leq i \leq q)\\
MAC & = e_K(d_{K'}(H_q)).
\end{align}

If we re-write the equation

\begin{align}
H_1 & = e_K(D_1) \\
H_i & = e_K(D_i \oplus H_{i-1}), \quad (2 \leq i \leq q-1)\\
MAC & = e_K(d_{K'}(e_K((D_q \oplus H_{q-1}))).
\end{align}

The Triple-DES (EDE) will appear in the end.

**The attacks on DES Retail MAC**

The attack on DES Retail MAC formalized as four tuple $[a,b,c,d]$ where

- $a$ is  the number of offline block cipher encipherments
- $b$ denotes the number of known data string/MAC pairs
- $c$ denotes the number of chosen data string/MAC pairs
- $d$ denotes the number of on-line MAC verifications, and
- $k$ is key size
- $n$ is the block size
- $m$ is the zeros of padding.

1. On 1996, Preneel and Oorschot achieved  $[2^{k+1},2^{n/2},0,0]$ on
   [Key recovery attack on ANSI X9.19 retail MAC](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/533295)
2. On 1998, Knudsen and Preneel achieved $[2^k,1,0,2^k]$ on
   [MacDES: MAC algorithm based on DES](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/682820)
3. On, 2002 Mitchell achieved $[2^{k+1},0,0,(\lceil n/m \rceil +1) 2^{(n+m)/2-1}]$ on [A new key recovery attack on the ANSI retail MAC](http://www.chrismitchell.net/ankrao.pdf)

Therefore, if there is no specific usage, don't use it.

Comment: Note that the bouncy castle has an [implementation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/macs/ISO9797Alg3Mac.html) for it.

Comment: Impressive information! Besides, are there anywhere which I can access documentation of `ISO/IEC 9797-1 algorithm 3` for free? Documents of ISO in PDF format are for purchase. I want to know how could you access these pieces of information?

Comment: I don't know. I've looked around but failed.